# not able to connect to the puppet master

Tags: puppet

I am having a solo setup where both master and agent are installed on a single node. While trying to connecting the master i am getting this error.

```
$ puppet agent --test --server XXXXXX
Info: Retrieving plugin 
Error: /File[/home/ppower_test/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/home/ppower_test/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///plugins
```

In puppet.conf i specified pluginsync = true in client section

Comment: Any errors logged by the master process?

Comment: no .. no errors while starting the master , its succesfully starting on 8140 port , even agent is starting fine . But while giving  the test command getting that error.

Comment: The master might write a log *while* the agent is connecting. To debug further, you can stop the master and restart with `--no-daemonize --debug --verbose`.

Comment: yes i did tried to restart the master with --no-daemonize --debug --verbose  , getting to see that master has started succesfully , while debugging the   --test cmd , i am getting this errror      
Error: /File[/home/ppower_test/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///pluginfacts        
Error: /File[/home/ppower_test/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///plugins

Comment: Yes. You pasted that **in** your question already. While it's nice to know that the master has started up successfully, you should carefully watch what it's logging **when the agent connects** to it.